# Getting txt from jar & stucked

Tags: java, jar, text-files

I currently started programming a board game playground which can load different games. I store these games in file named config.txt, but I am having trouble accessing it. Firstly, I started with my favourite file approach:

```
String fileAddress = "./resources/config.txt";
fis = new FileInputStream(fileAddress);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

But then when I built .jar file, it stopped working. For obvious reasons. So I found myself looking around and I found about recommendation to use getResourceAsStream(String s) method. So I changed my code to following way:

```
String fileAddress = "./resources/config.txt";
InputStream toReturn=null;
toReturn = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileAddress);
```

But here I got stuck. No matter how I tweak the fileAddress (tried ./config.txt ./resources/config.txt ./resources/boardgames/config.txt and ./resources/boardgames/config.txt) and both using or omitting getClassLoader(), the result of toReturn just always equals NULL and ends up throwing NullPointerException very soon.

Location of required file follows. As I do not have enough reputation, I will have to ASCII art the file hierarchy. Both config.txt are valid targets.

On File System:

```
Boardgames
   src
   cache
   classes
   resources
      boardgames
         config.txt
      imgs
      config.txt
```

Inside Jar File

```
BoardGames.jar
    boardgames
       <class files>
       config.txt
    imgs
    META-INF
    config.txt
```

Therefore I would need an assistance with repairing the code so that it would read the file properly. If you could include tips how to get ImageIcon from the .png files located in subfolders imgs, since I reckon I will run into similar problem once I get past the initialization phase via config.txt.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: habit from unix while transcripting. It does not work even without them (like "/config.txt" ) anyway

Comment: Did you try `boardgames/config.txt`?

Comment: yup. /boardgames/config.txt, boardgames/config.txt, and some more as mentioned in post. Still returns null

Comment: If that's really what you have in the .jar file, " /boardgames/config.txt" will work. Try it as `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/boardgames/config.txt");`

Comment: pity I can't post images yet. But I swapped to this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/boardgames/config.txt"); with no avail, but then I tried other versions and @immibis 's version (the one without the first slash) worked, at least for the text file. I am off to tinker with the icons now, since they broke down as well, so thank you ALL very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @EJP and @immibis for all help.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("boardgames/config.txt");
```

was the solution that finally got me running