# java project runs in eclipse but not correct in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm facing weird problem. When I run my project in eclipse everything works good. When I export project into executeable jar file and run it it just loads plain `JFrame`.

How should I find problem? I have no idea what can be wrong. I think problem can be here but do not know:

```
try {
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("maps/"+ level +".txt");
    File file = new File(url.getFile());
    fr = new FileReader(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    in = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268508/getting-txt-from-jar-stucked/29268696#29268696 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are reading the resource is not correct. Try using something like:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/maps/1.txt")));
    br.readLine();
```

Comment: sry I haven't understand you, I used absolute path and it works correctly, thanks. However how to achieve it without absolute path?

Comment: No. You've used a relative path. You didn't begin with the "/" :) In order to use a relative path, you obviously form the path relative to your current class.

Comment: oh I see, but with that is neither working in eclipse nor in jar. I used absolute path like "C:\\Users\\Me..." and it works in that way but it's just bad workaround

Comment: No dude. An absolut path to your classpath. Lol. The leading "/" has the meaning of the root of your project.

Comment: I know but I'm telling you it's not working in any way

Comment: then it means the maps directory isn't in your project's classpath. Place it in src and it will work.

Comment: well it's there :-D when I print out your code it's null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74126/discussion-between-dsf-and-donthavename).

Comment: Calling `.getClassLoader()` isn't necessary. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268508/getting-txt-from-jar-stucked/29268696#29268696

Comment: then it's setting me url into bin/maps/1.txt

Answer (score 0):

try using below solution , System.getProperty() will give you the current directory path :

**- Code snippet:**

```
InputStream input = null;
try{
    String dirPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String completePath= dirPath+fileName;
    input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(completePath);
}catch(IOException ioex){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: tried that, when I printed out completePath path was correctly, but again when I compile it in jar it's not working